# unlock the screen lock using UiScroller

Tags: android-uiautomator, screen-lock

I am trying to unlock the screen lock by swiping forward and for that I have used UiScroller.

Methiod1:

```
UiScrollable scrollUnlock = new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().packageName("com.android.systemui").className("android.view.ViewGroup").resourceId("com.android.systemui:id/notification_stack_scroller"));
scrollUnlock.scrollForward();
```

This method sometimes work and sometimes does not work.  Any suggestions please.

Method 2:

```
UiObject scrollUnlock = device.findObject(new UiSelector().packageName("com.android.systemui").className("android.view.ViewGroup").resourceId("com.android.systemui:id/notification_stack_scroller").enabled(true).index(1).scrollable(true));
scrollUnlock.scrollable();
```

This method does not work.

Please suggest some ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `getUiDevice().swipe()`

code:-

```
public void unlockBySwipe() throws UiObjectNotFoundException, Exception {
  x1 = getUiDevice().getDisplayWidth()/2;
  y1 = getUiDevice().getDisplayHeight()/2;
  x2 = getUiDevice().getDisplayWidth()/3;
  y2 = getUiDevice().getDisplayHeight()/3;
  getUiDevice().swipe(x1,y1,x2,y2, 10);
  getUiDevice().waitForIdle()
}
```